# Magento 2 REST API get all enabled categories

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Wanted to use REST API to get all categories where `is_active` attribute is `true`.

Here is endpoint I am calling `https://www.domain.com/rest/default/V1/categories`

Which giving me all the categories is_active is true and false.

I tried to add filters but didnt work either.

```
https://www.domain.com/rest/default/V1/categories?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=is_active&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=true&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

Could someone help how to apply filter on category to get only active categories?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code in Postman you will find all the categories

```
Endpoint: “http(s)://yourdomain.com/rest/ V1/categories/list”

Method: GET
Request: searchCriteria.
Header: Authorization : Bearer (Token)
Response: token(string)
```

Reference : [This is a reference link for the code](https://www.tigren.com/get-categories-magento-2-api/)

Also, try replacing the " list " with the default category Id. Say Default Category Id is 2. Then  the endpoint will be below

```
Endpoint: “http(s)://yourdomain.com/rest/V1/categories/2”
```

Try below:

```
Endpoint - http://yourdomain.com/index.php/rest/all/V1/categories
```

Note: Make sure you pass all keyword in Url and it will works

Comment: I used list but this endpoint doesn't provide  category hierarchy.. its just plain list.

Comment: @VK321 please check the updated answer

Comment: Hi Rid.. Thanks but as I said I am looking for "all categories" not single. 2 in your endpoint will bring only single category with id 2.

Comment: @VK321 updated the answer

Comment: Thanks that you trying to help but not sure if you understood my question properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=is_active& '+
    'searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=1& '+
    'searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=eq& '+
```

Value must = 1! not true! :)